# AIX are mutexes sempahores?

Tags: pthreads, mutex, semaphore, aix

First question: will ipcs -s display any information about pthread mutexes in use?

I ask in case pthread mutexes are implemented on top of the AIX semaphores or maybe vice versa.

Someone has spotted some semaphores hanging about (using ipcs) and indicated it may be in our library. However we don't use semxxx but use pthread mutexes.

The mutexes are not shared so I'm assuming they die along with the process?

Answer (score 0):

They are separate.   Pthreads are implemented a user space library, not as a kernel subsystem like SysV style semaphores are.    All pthread concepts are local to that process.   Pthreads themselves can map up to kernel threads, but the locking concepts are separate.